# How to set masonryhorizontal layout in Isotope

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I'm just a newbie when it comes to jquery, so I'm just editing my scripts through modifications. I used isotope for my experiment and here's the result: 
http://rvflores.com/SM-SCROLL/

I need help for the container to appear in masonryHorizontal layout mode without me having to click on the button on the top part to change it. I read the documentation but I can't seem to find how they set it, so I just copied the script from their website.

Any help and suggestions are welcome, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

### For anyone who missed the *actual* answer in the comments:

The [documentation for masonryHorixontal](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/layout-modes.html#masonryhorizontal) is missing the `layoutMode` property.
The correct code would be:

```
$('#container').isotope({
    layoutMode: 'masonryHorizontal',
    masonryHorizontal: {
        rowHeight: 360
    }
});
```

This issue is also the cause of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155985/jquery-isotope-plugin-horizontal-scrolling).