# jQuery isotope plugin horizontal scrolling

Tags: jquery

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xKjUv/19/) - just want it to scroll horizontally according to [documentation example](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/layout-modes.html). I've no idea why it is not working.

```
$('#container').isotope({
  masonry: {
    columnWidth: 240
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to use the option `layoutMode` that tells it to use the horizontal layout.

```
$('#container').isotope({
    layoutMode: 'masonryHorizontal',
    masonryHorizontal: {
        rowHeight: 160
    },
    resizesContainer: false
});
```

*notice: the documentation seems to be missing that too, but mentions it for all other options so you can infer it*